# Confuse about javascript increment operator

Tags: javascript, operators, expression, increment

Here is a simple demo:

```
var foo = 1;
foo = foo++;
console.log(foo) // 1
```

Why the `foo` result is `1`, not `2`?

I think the `foo++` expression return the `1` first, but then it increase itself to `2`, override the `1` value,  so why the `foo` result is not `2`?

Comment: The increase doesn't happen when the semicolon is met, but right before the expression `foo++` yields `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code causes these operations to happen in this order:

1. `foo++` evaluates as `1`
2. `foo` is incremented by `++` to `2`
3. `1` (the results of evaluating the expression) is passed left
4. `foo = 1` causes that value to be assigned to `foo` (overwriting the `2`).

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not fully sure, but What according to [*operator precedence*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) I think in this line

```
foo = foo++;
```

**1)** The `++` operator has higher precedence. What it has to do return the current value of `foo` which is one. After that increment the value of `foo`.

**2)** The `=` operator has lower precedence, So it'll get the returned value from operation `++` which is `1` and it'll set the value of `foo` to `1`. Because the increment happen between these two operations, So it looses it's value. And the final value of `foo` is `1`.

Because I'm not full sure, If there is any problem correct me. Thank you.